# Implementing gerrit command in Jgit

Tags: git, gerrit, jgit

I want to implement this commmand in Git,But I don't know what to do?

```
push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjgit%5D+push

Answer (score -1):

Try something like the following example:

```
public static void push(String remoteUrl, Repository repo, StandardCredentials credential, String localBranchRef, String remoteBranchRef) {
    try (org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git git = new org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git(repo)) {
        String pushSpec = "+" + localBranchRef + ":" + remoteBranchRef;
        PushCommand pushCommand = git.push();

        addCredential(repo, pushCommand, credential);

        Iterable<PushResult> resultIterable = pushCommand
            .setRefSpecs(new RefSpec(pushSpec))
            .setRemote(remoteUrl)
            .call();
        PushResult result = resultIterable.iterator().next();
        if (result.getRemoteUpdates().isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No remote updates occurred");
        } else {
            for (RemoteRefUpdate update : result.getRemoteUpdates()) {
                if (!RemoteRefUpdate.Status.OK.equals(update.getStatus())) {
                    throw new ServiceException.UnexpectedErrorException("Remote update failed: " + update.getStatus().name() + ": " + update.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (GitAPIException e) {
        if (e.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains("auth")) {
            throw new ServiceException.UnauthorizedException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        throw new ServiceException.UnexpectedErrorException("Unable to save and push to: " + remoteUrl + " - " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

You can find more info and examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.eclipse.jgit.api.PushCommand).

Comment: Sorry,Do you know how to implement this command in JGIT?

Comment: Thank you. After trying, I found that changeId was missing, so it was not successful!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30677910)

Comment: @NicoHaase I added the relevant part to the answer.